# Различия установки ios прилоежния через itunes и xcode

Tags: ios

Коллеги, доброе время суток!

Возникла проблема с приложением которое я разрабатываю под ios для iphone. Суть проблемы в том, что если я запускаю приложение через xcode или уже установленное через xcode то приложение запускается и выполняет все что от него требуется. Но если я делаю сборку и устанавливаю это же приложение через iTunes то часть функционала приложения перестает работать. Вопрос: Чем отличаются сборки? Почему разрабатываемая мной версия установленная на телефон через xcode работает а установленная через iTunes работает с глюками?

Comment: я вот спросить хотел, что значит "устанавливаю это же приложение через iTunes"? Это как это? И по существу вопроса - а в логах телефона разве ничего нет? Никаких ошибок?

Comment: "устанавливаю это же приложение через iTunes" - это значит что я делаю архив приложения, подписываю его как ad-hoc и ставлю через itunes на телефон как обычное приложение.

верез утилиту iphone configuration utility я смотрел логи, там вижу весь вывод логов nslog но в момент зависания никаких ошибок нет, пробовал на разных моделях телефонов с ios 7.

Comment: какой-то странный способ, откровенно говоря. Я не уверен, что то что Вы делаете вообще должно работать. Я знаю лишь одно, что если программа загруженная на телефон через Xcode будет работать как следует и после того как она появится в аппсторе.

Comment: до вчерашнего дня я тоже был уверен. но факты говорят сами за себя.

Comment: Вот этот способ вы считаете фактом? Если программа протестирована локально и весь код проверен и выверен как следует - проблем не возникает, или их возникновение сводится к нулю. Но так чтобы совсем все не работало, я такого еще не видел.

Comment: программ установленная через itunes работает но частично.

Comment: это не странный способ, это штатный способ поделиться своей программой с тетстерами-не собирать же им ее заново из исходников, да и с привязкой крашлогов будут проблемы если версии xcode не совпадут, но я уже написал в своем ответе, там есть хитрость с тем что сборки Debug и Release не совсем идентичны, а способы эти по умолчанию для xcode и тунца разные.Даже запущеная с помощью run из среды и та же сборка просто с устройства без подключения к xcode работают с разной скоростью. Можете еще попробовать в проекте поискать #ifdef DEBUG-блоки, может в них что по разному обрабатывается

Comment: установленные приложения через itunes работают также в debug  режиме это подтверждает вывол логов nslog который в блоке #ifdef DEBUG. 
Мне бы всеже хотелось более конкретно узнать в чем различия и как этого избежать в дальнейшем.

Comment: И еще вариант- насколько я помню, xcode по умолчанию льет новую версию поверх старого бандла, а тунец делает новый бандл и копирует в него документы и настройки из старого, что приводит к двум следствиям:

1.xcode может адекватно работать если вы затерли какой-нибудь ресурс в проекте, но он остался болтаться в бандле (а  иногда и в неочищенном проекте в подготовленых бинарниках)

2.если вы где-то вычислили и сохранили путь до чего-нибудь в настройках (а он дается в абсолютном виде) и потом залили версию из тунца поверх, он будет ссылаться на старый бандл которого уже нет

Comment: Отсекается и то и другое через очистку проекта и доплнительные проверки именно на миграцию с версии на версию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через айтюнс это архивирование-экспорт в ипа? Как вариант - возможно у вас стоят разные сборки - отладочная через xcode и релиз через тунец, отладочная может работать медленнее за счет дополнительного логирования (сам видел как ошибка проявлялась только на релизе т.к. в дебаге логирование притормаживало доппоток и он не успевал убить переменные). Вообще вы бы поточнее написали что за функционал у вас отключился

Comment: пишется приложения для сканирования qr-code . с помощью приложения считается штрих код в результате сканирования полученный код передается на сервер который отдает мобильному приложения описание товара. В релизной версии после сканирования этикетки сканер зависает и больше ничего не происходит. В отладочной версии все как задумано.

Comment: для сканирования использую ZBarSDK (1.3.1)